# Send Private chat message

Tags: jquery

i am working on a web based chat. I need to implement gtalk like popups for private chat.for this i need to open a popup on the screen of destination user . is it possible to send some notification or open popup in diffrent sessions using session id.

Answer (score 1):

If you have less traffic a server sided chat with a polling mechanism should be sufficient. But as far as I know the easiest way for different sessions to communicate is probably to save all chat messages in a database. jQuery polls (e.g. every 5 seconds) that database with the current users session id and retrieves the new messages (btw. Facebook implemented their chat in Erlang because it needs to be highly scalable and distributed).

Answer (score 0):

use session with polling

Answer (score 0):

Websockets can be used for chat application. HTML 5 support websocket on browser now.